# {} no retorno do require()

Tags: javascript, node.js

Eu estou criando um módulo, mas quando vou utilizar ele, recebo um objeto vazio no require()

Códigos abaixo:

dev/index.js

```js
module.exports = () => {
  'use strict';

  const names = require('./names.js'),
  findSuperman = require('./find.js');


  if ( findSuperman(names()) )
    console.log('O superman está dentro de names');
  else
    console.log('O superman não está aqui');

}
```

dev/names.js

```js
module.exports = () => ['Barry Allen', 'Hal Jordan', 'Kara Kent', 'Diana Prince', 'Ray Palmer', 'Oliver Queen', 'Bruce Wayne', 'Wally West', 'John Jones', 'Kyle Rayner', 'Arthur Curry', 'Clark Kent'];
```

dev/find.js

```js
module.exports = (values) => {
  'use strict';
  let foundSuperman = false;

  values.forEach(name => {
    if (name === 'Clark Kent')
      foundSuperman = true;
  });

  return foundSuperman;
}
```

Daí, ao executar o browserify

```
browserify dev/index.js -o out.js
```

out.js

```js
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
module.exports = (values) => {
  'use strict';
  let foundSuperman = false;

  values.forEach(name => {
    if (name === 'Clark Kent')
      foundSuperman = true;
  });

  return foundSuperman;
}

},{}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
module.exports = () => {
  'use strict';

  const names = require('./names.js'),
  findSuperman = require('./find.js');


  if ( findSuperman(names()) )
    console.log('O superman está dentro de names');
  else
    console.log('O superman não está aqui');

}

},{"./find.js":1,"./names.js":3}],3:[function(require,module,exports){
module.exports = () => ['Barry Allen', 'Hal Jordan', 'Kara Kent', 'Diana Prince', 'Ray Palmer', 'Oliver Queen', 'Bruce Wayne', 'Wally West', 'John Jones', 'Kyle Rayner', 'Arthur Curry', 'Clark Kent'];

},{}]},{},[2]);
```

Até aí, tudo bem :)
Porém...
Tento fazer um teste e não rola :/

```js
'use strict';

const oi = require('./out.js');
console.log(oi);

// O retorno é: {}
```

Comment: Porque tens a variável `findSuperman = require('./find.js');` não declarada? Já testaste a colocar essas duas linhas (requires) fora da função que estás a exportar? ou seja, no inicio do ficheiro `dev/index.js`? Esse tipo de erro do Browserify acontece-me quando há erros de _lint_ / sintaxe no código.

Comment: 1- Está declarada como const em `dev/index.js`. 2- Fiz o que você falou. Mas ocorreu-me de receber `{}` de novo :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia!

Acredito que você está aprendendo ES6 e Browserify, certo? Acho que eu entendi as suas dúvidas, então vamos lá:

Os arquivos dev/names.js e dev/find.js retornam funções utilizando a notação *arrow-function*. O arquivo dev/index.js também retorna uma função, porém ela nunca é executada! Tente alterar esse arquivo para somente

```
  const names = require('./names.js'),
        findSuperman = require('./find.js');


  if ( findSuperman(names()) )
    alert('O superman está dentro de names');
  else
    alert('O superman não está aqui');
```

Execute o comando `browserify dev/index.js -o out.js` no terminal e adicione o script gerado a um arquivo HTML e abra no navegador. Após fazer isso, você perceberá que um alert foi exibido com a mensagem "O superman está dentro de names".

Sobre o Browserify, seu objetivo é escrever código JS usando módulos do NodeJS (CommonJS) e depois fazê-lo rodar no navegador.

Comment: Perdão por não ter visualizado antes, estive um pouco ausente. Enfim, achei estranho porque não tive o resultado esperado mesmo com IIFE. Porém da sua maneira funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado!